# Angular ng build command bundles static JSON file to main TS file. How to keep it in asset folder without bundling it in main TS file?

Tags: angular

I have a JSON file kept in the asset folder and I am importing it in my .ts component. And whenever I build the project with ng build —prod the JSON file will be bundled inside the main.**.ts file, and if I change any content in the JSON file it will be not reflected in the angular app as it is reading the data from main.**.ts file. But this doesn’t fit my requirement. What I need is, the static JSON file should be in the asset folder itself, and when we access the angular app it should read the JSON data from the JSON file kept in the asset folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should instead follow this strategy. You can use httpclient and call the data from the JSON file. You can create a separate service to read JSON file, or you can get this method in any other service.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
```

Inject Http in constructor

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
```

```
public getJson() {

    this.httpClient.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(data => {
            // do anything thing with data 
            console.log(data);
    })
}
```

I think this way when you change anything in your JSON file you don't need to create build again.

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. But, I was checking the possibility by using a direct import and not using subscribe for static JSON contents. Is there any way of doing this or subscribe is the only approach which can be followed?

Comment: As soon as you import it in your component file, it becomes the dependency and will be added to main file when you build the project. As you mentioned, you need not to make json a part of ts file. At the moment, I think only of this approach.

Comment: Did you find any other solution?

Comment: followed http service, accepted the answer, thank you, sry for delay in accepting the answer.

Comment: this would slow down the initial load of the app, especially if the json is required to perform some initial logic. It does not work in my case